# How to show keyboard without touching the UISearchbar?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uisearchbar

Can I show the keyboard for `UISearchbar` on `viewWillAppear` method call without touching the `UISearchbar` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
[mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 1):

Working Solution:-

Don't use [self.searchController setActive:YES] before becomeFirstResponder.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
         [super viewDidAppear:animated];
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //[self.searchController setActive:YES];
         [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
       });
   });
}
```